# TYPO3 Fluidcontent - load page via pagenum

Tags: ajax, typo3, typo3-8.x, tx-fluidcontent

In older projects (< TYPO3 7.6) I was using the following code to load a page with a pagenum:

```
ajax = PAGE
ajax {
    typeNum = 2008

    10 < styles.content.get
    10.stdWrap.innerWrap >

    config {
        disableAllHeaderCode = 1
        additionalHeaders = Content-type:application/json
        disablePrefixComment = 1
        xhtml_cleaning = 0
        admPanel = 0
        debug = 0
        no_cache = 1
    }
}
```

Now we're working with TYPO3 8.7 and Fluidcontent and when using this code, a blank page is being outputted, no content. I had a look into the Object-Browser and it seems that `styles.content.get` should still work.

I'm afraid it doesn't work anymore because of Fluidcontent and the different structure for backend layouts. Unfortunately, I could not find anything helpful on Google. Does anybody know how to use this (load page via pagenum) with Fluidcontent in TYPO3 8.7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`styles.content.get` is defined very late with fluidcontent. so your copy might copy an up to then undefined/ empty definition.

- either use the reference operator `=<`,
- define it by your own:

.

```
styles.content.get = CONTENT
styles.content.get {
    table = tt_content
    select {
        orderBy = sorting
        where = colPos=0
    } 
}
```

- or use this immediately:

.

```
ajax {
    10 = CONTENT
    10 {
        table = tt_content
        select {
            orderBy = sorting
            where = colPos=0
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that last snippet was the one I needed.